# How to setup responsive navigation using Sitecore SXA navigation component?

Tags: sxa, responsive-design

Is there a way to build responsive navigation using build in navigation component in Sitecore SXA?

I tried to apply `navigation-mobile` class, but it doesn't adapt the mobile layout.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you explain what do you mean by responsive navigation? If you describe your expected behavior more precisely (images will be welcome) I will tell you if this is possible or not.

Comment: I am looking for description of navigation classes. Which classes should apply to navigation items so it can adapt mobile layout? Also hide under main navigation doesn't work for me as well. Thank you for your help in advance. Do you know any demo site or tutorial/videos etc?

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. I still don't know what are your expectations.

Comment: Sorry.  Let me rephrase the question. How do I get the Navigation component to work in SxA? Any Demo site or sample would be useful. Thank you

Comment: Let me know if this article works for you. https://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2018/02/hamburger-menu-in-sxa.html

Answer (score 1):

A quick way is to use the Toggle component.

1. Add a Toggle component where you want your "menu" toggle should be.
2. Put a Navigation component with `navigation-mobile` class in the toggle's placeholder.
3. Update the old navigation component's visibilty under the Grid's Advance tab to only show up on Desktops and Large Desktops.
4. Update the Toggle's visibility to only show up for Phones and Tablets.

Of course this isn't optimized and may not even look close to what you need but it is a responsive mobile nav.

If you want another solution, you can [take a look at my blog post](https://marcotanainsights.wordpress.com/2018/01/25/sitecore-experience-accelerator-sxa-quick-responsive-mobile-nav/).

Comment: Blog post link is empty. Please update the link. Thanks

Comment: Ooops....updated.

Answer (score -1):

For navigation component to work, you need to create that page under Home item, using Page data template. After that, add navigation component in your page and select the style as `horizontal/vertical/sidebar`.